# What to enter in profile Path & logon while creating new user

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

While creating users, what is the purpose of entering profile path and logon script?
What are the values to be entered to configure them in a standard scenario.
Logon script has to be written in which language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer the actual question, you should know this: Generally, you don't want to configure either of these on a per-user basis. You would configure them across domains or OUs using Group Policy. They're a hold-over from the olden days. Don't use them unless you have a *compelling* reason to.

> Logon script has to be written in which language.

Batch, CMD, or VBScript.

> While creating what is the purpose of entering profile path and logon script?

To run a script on a per-user basis at logon and to redirect the user's profile to a different location. Usually a network share.

Comment: Thank you I would need your help for this question as well please. http://serverfault.com/questions/432367/creating-roaming-profile-for-users-on-ad-domain-server-using-group-policy

Answer (score 2):

Logon script is a batch file or VBScript file that is executed on the client machine at login time. You could use such a file to map network drives for instance.

Profile path is used to override where the user's profile is stored. If you want to use roaming profiles on your network you would enter a server share. e.g. \server\users\%username%. Now the user's my documents, settings and desktop etc will be stored on the server so that when they log in on any of the machines in your domain they get the same desktop, my documents and settings.

Comment: What is performance cost associated with having roaming profile ?

Comment: @autrevo My experience with roaming profiles has been that it can be quite fiddly to get set up correctly. Incorrect setup can result in poor network performance and slow login / logoff times. You only need roaming profiles when you have hot desk swapping really. In a standard work environment where one person uses one machine its not worth implementing. It might be more useful to give people a mapped network drive and tell them to use that. but MDMarra is right in that you should set this up in Group Policies rather than using Profile Path.