# Store user My Documents folder on server

Tags: active-directory, windows

EDIT: Rephrased this question to convey the message precisely.

A user, **(user1)** use to login into multiple computers on the domain using his password, say **(user1/password1)**

He needs My Documents, folder to be stored on the domain controller. So that he could see same set of files, on each client PC when he login.

How can I obtain this. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: You need to be *way* more specific. How are you loading/unloading the profiles? What GPOs apply? Where is the file server? Are you doing offline files? What does the event log say? Etc.

Comment: @MDMarra Domain controller itself has additional role of file server as of now.

Answer (score 2):

Folder Redirection is the feature you want to control just the location of My Documents. Find it under the User Policy in a Group Policy Object. You can just set a network path for My Documents (and/or most other profile folders), and then give him the only permissions to the GPO so it only affects him.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If I read the question correctly you want all newly created accounts to have roaming profiles. I'm not sure if that is possible but there is a very easy way to achieve the desired results. Simply create one user account that has all the settings you want new accounts to have and use that as a template when creating new accounts.